# ¿De dónde es? pronunciation

Tags: pronunciación

I'm listening to the pronunciation from [spanishdict](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/de%20d%C3%B3nde%20es), the woman pronounces it twice, the first time the whole phrase at once and the second time she spells it. Sometimes **d** sounds like **d** from **d**octor and sometimes it sound like **th** from **th**en (like Greek letter **δ**), and the strange thing is that I hear different pronunciations at different speeds. Is it just me? Are there any rules or both ways are correct?

Comment: That is normal everywhere.  It's the sound that a D makes intervocalically (between vowels).

Comment: @guifa I agree that d sounds differently between vowels but I can pronounce this phrase both ways, does it mean that both ways are correct?

Comment: La verdad es que cuando uno aprende español nativo no nos enseñan a diferenciar sonoramente la  consonante D si va al comienzo o entre vocales, y teóricamente tiene un único sonido. Yo no logro distinguir diferencia al escuchar la grabación a la que hace referencia.

Comment: In spanish D has a unique sound, no matter begin or between vowels. Maybe you hear diference because the first syllable of word "dónde" has a strong sound.

Comment: The 'slow' recording on spanishdict isn't the full phrase but each syllable recorded individually and spliced together.

Comment: @alvalongo The sound /d/ does have several possible realizations, which are predictable from context.

Comment: In *"De dónde eres"* the second /d/ should be pronounced like the *th* in *then* because it's between vowels; elsewhere as in *doctor*. See if the answer to the question I've linked above works for you.

Comment: @pablodf76, yo no distingo diferencia de pronunciación e insisto que en el proceso ni en los libros de lecto-escritura existe mención alguna de que la consonante "D" tenga 2 sonidos diferentes.

Comment: @alvalongo Es posible que no lo distingas y que no se enseñe, pero la diferencia existe y está bien documentada. Un ejemplo en un [documento de la RAE](https://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Sala_prensa_Dosier_Fonetica_y_fonologia.pdf) (PDF; ver pág. 16, sección 4.2f).

Comment: @pablodf76, Ud. confirma lo que digo NO se enseña explícitamente que existan esos 2 sonidos, y seguramente con la práctica diaria lo hacemos sin pensar en ello, y para la persona que pregunta, la respuesta es sencillamente que no tiene que preocuparse por este asunto y que no vale la pena racionalizar mucho el tema, ya que igualmente los que hablamos español le vamos a entender.

Comment: @alvalongo He dicho que no sé si no se enseña. Por supuesto los hablantes nativos no necesitamos aprenderlo explícitamente, y los estudiantes no nativos que tengan buen oído pueden captarlo sin darse cuenta. Eso no significa que la diferencia no exista o que no haya reglas (y sobre eso es la pregunta). Sobre la necesidad de preocuparse por el asunto no opino.